# Laravel migrate error

Tags: apache, laravel, session, migrate

I have a weird error when I lunch any migrate command (reset refresh rollback etc..), the error is :

```
  [ErrorException]
  session_start(): open({APACHEPATH}/sessions\sess_0pb5924dau2oehuo4h32lqnem3
  , O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)



PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Unknown: ope
n({APACHEPATH}/sessions\sess_0pb5924dau2oehuo4h32lqnem3, O_RDWR) failed: No such
 file or directory (2)' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle
Error(2, 'Unknown: open({...', 'Unknown', 0, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in Unknown on line 0
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\UwAmp\www\project\artisan:0
```

The session id

> sess_0pb5924dau2oehuo4h32lqnem3

differs is different each time, so I went to the apache sessions folder (C:\UwAmp\bin\apache\sessions) and that session id was not present.
I should mention that this problem occurred while installing the [Tracker package](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#installing) , somehow during the process i can't migrate anymore, any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: does it happen with other artisan commands too? for example, php artisan make:model TestModel?

Comment: @FatemehMajd No, only migrate commands, I made a fresh project and copied the advancement from the old one, couldn't figure out what the problem was

Comment: can you explain more about those advancements? what exactly did you copy and how? did you use the command line or copy/past through file manager?

Comment: @FatemehMajd The advancements are my controllers, views, models etc .. I copied everything through the file manager, and did not install the Tracker package, since I believe (Not sure though) that something happened during the installing process

Answer (score 1):

I definitely think your php.ini's `session.save_path` is not configured correctly, especially as I'm seeing a forward slash "/" in the path to the directory to save sessions in within your error message.

Try this:

1. Create a new file within your Laravel install called *info.php* with just a call to `phpinfo()`.
2. Navigate to *info.php*. Under "Loaded Configuration File", find the path to the loaded *php.ini* file and open it in your favourite text editor.
3. Add / change the following line: `session.save_path = C:\wamp\temp\` - assuming that this is the correct path to the temp folder and it actually exists on your system. Do a bit of research to determine where this directory lives and adjust accordingly, and make sure that the path uses "\" and not any "/".
4. Restart WAMP and try to run your migrations again.